# Angular 4 Material custom color for component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to add custom (HEX) color to material component in Angular 4?
For example something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let factor of factors">
   <button md-button color="factor.color">Button</button>
</div>
```

Where factor.color is string in hex format (for example '#CCC')

Comment: Old post I know.. but the answer is that you should have [color]="factor.color" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [style.color] attribute and some helpful posts about converting hexa code to RGB:

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/U4q8bWyUFK7nmEN33Vc1?p=preview)**

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-button [style.color]="hexToRgb(factor.color)">Click me</button>
```

**Typescript**:

```
....

hexToRgb(hex) {
  hex = hex.replace("#",'');
  let arrBuff = new ArrayBuffer(4);
  let vw = new DataView(arrBuff);
  vw.setUint32(0,parseInt(hex, 16),false);
  let arrByte = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);

  return 'rgb(' + arrByte[1] + "," + arrByte[2] + "," + arrByte[3] +')';
}
```

Comment: For the convertor I used this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508164/5468463